# Is irrational number set on $\mathbb{R}$ disconnected?

Tags: real-analysis, connectedness, irrational-numbers

I thought that irrational numbers on $\mathbb{R}$ must be disconnected, since for every pair of irrational numbers, we have infinitely many rational numbers between this two hence they do not touch each other at all. But I couldn't form a disconnection between them. Is my reasoning true, and if it is false could you provide me why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The sets $(\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q})\cap \{x\in\mathbb{R}:\ x<0\}$ and $(\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q})\cap \{x\in\mathbb{R}:\ x>0\}$ are non-empty (contain $\pm\sqrt{2}$ respectively), open (intersection of $\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$ with open intervals of $\mathbb{R}$), disjoint, and their union is all of $\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean by "disconnected"? If it means that there exists a point $r \in \Bbb{R}$ between $q_1, q_2 \in \Bbb{R}$ such that $r$ isn't irrational, and $q_1$ and $q_2$ are, then you've already proved that the set is disconnected by choosing any $r \in \Bbb{Q}$ number.

Comment: @DanielP Well a set $S$ is disconnected if there exists sets $S_1$ and $S_2$ disjoint and form S s.t. $S_1 \cap\bar{S_2}$= $\emptyset$ and $\bar{S_1} \cap$ ${S_2}$= $\emptyset$ too. I want to see such sets, and I received an answer, thanks for your concern too!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the sets $(-\infty,0)\setminus\mathbb Q$ and $(0,\infty)\setminus\mathbb Q$. Each of these sets is a non-empty open subset of $\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$ and they are disjoint. Therefore, $\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$ is disconnected.

Answer (score 1):

Not only are the Rationals disconnected but they are totally disconnected. Every single Rational $q_i $  gives rise to a disconnection $(- \infty,q_i), (q_i, + \infty)$ so that connected components are singletons. Any neighborhood of the Irrationals can be disconnected in this way.

Comment: So, please explain the downvote.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1755992/mathbb-q-is-totally-disconnected-what-is-the-open-set-in-subspace-of-mathb

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1314013/components-of-the-set-of-rational-numbers

Comment: Enjoy abusing your power in anonimity.