# Is $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ connected?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, connectedness, rational-numbers

In case of $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ we can construct two open sets union of which is $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ but here we eliminate infinitely many uncountable points then how we can construct open sets?
I am confused. Sorry for language error. Thank you...

Comment: $\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q^{c}=\mathbb Q$. No countable set with more than one point is connected.

Comment: Okay. I understood. Can I prove this is disconnected in this way, (-infty, 0) int Q union (0, infty) int Q = Q. Thank you.

Comment: What's a poen set?

Comment: Please typeset your mathematics. It is difficult to read what you're trying to say (and it may be ambiguous as a result). Use `$((-\infty, 0) \cup (0, \infty)) \cap \mathbb{Q}$` to get $((-\infty, 0) \cup (0, \infty)) \cap \mathbb{Q}$, for example. ¶ As it stands, your assertion looks false. The left-hand side lacks $0$, but the right-hand side contains it.

Comment: @DavidP: Almost surely a typo for "open set."

Comment: Yes, I will rectify my typing way. In my approach lesft side is not containing 0 but right contains 0. Then how to construct open sets such that we can say it is disconnected?

Comment: @DavidP a set all of whose points are interior points.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is irrational number set on $\mathbb{R}$ disconnected?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3431757/is-irrational-number-set-on-mathbbr-disconnected)

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{R}$ will become disconnected if you remove even a single point. For example, $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{3\}$ is disconnected because you can write it as a union $A \cup B$ where $A = (-\infty,3)$ and $B = (3, \infty)$ are two disjoint open sets.

The only way to remove stuff from $\mathbb{R}$ and get a connected set is if what's left is an interval. Otherwise, there'll always be two remaining points $a < b$ with a removed point $c$ in between, and you can use the same setup as above to break your set $S$ into nonempty open subsets $S \cap (-\infty,c)$ and $S \cap (c,\infty)$.

In general, the idea of "connected" is that it shouldn't be possible to break the set into two pieces that don't touch each other.

(Thanks @DanishChef for pointing out a math error in an earlier version of this answer.)

Comment: Understood, thank you.

Comment: $\mathbb{R} \setminus X$ isn't disconnected for any infinite set $X$. In particular $\mathbb{R} \setminus (0, \infty) = (-\infty, 0]$ is connected

Comment: @DanishChef Yep, you got me. Edited and credited :)

Comment: It was a duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3431757/is-irrational-number-set-on-mathbbr-disconnected