# $\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q$ the set of irrationals is disconnected

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness

I'm trying to find two non-empty disjoint open set $A, B$ such that $A \cup B = \Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q$.
But can't find

Comment: Can you find any non-empty subset of $\mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q}$ which is not everything?

Comment: Check this https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3431759/1093844

Comment: The endpoints of an interval don't have to be irrational.

Comment: Remember, the sets only need to be open in the subspace topology.